# Redirect URL's with index.php to wordpress default URL's doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i have questuon.

i moving from php based web site to wordpress system.
old links was  domains.com/index.php?Subject={Value} for example:
domains.com/index.php?Subject=Mistake-19 , domains.com/index.php?Subject=Mistake domains.com/index.php?Subject=Home_Content-31
new links is regular wordpress urls domain.com/?p={value}

i tried to create htaccess but it's doesn't work.
for example

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?Subject=Mistake-19 http://www.domain.com/?p=51
```

it's trasfer me to domain.com/?Subject=Mistake-19

also tried this:

```
rewriterule ^index.php?Subject=Mistake-19(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/?p=51$1 [r=301,nc]
```

still transfer to domain.com/?Subject=Mistake-19

how i can fix it?

Comment: Wild guess: try adding ' ' around the url's?

Comment: Just try it where ever you like, I'm just guessing

Comment: :( worth a try I use the 1rst example without the `301` you can try that. Doubt it will work...

Comment: i think the main problem is default wordpress redirect, index.php?p=51 transfer to ?p=51.
So /index.php?Subject=Mistake-19 redirected  automatic to /?Subject=Mistake-19 and ignore httaccess redirect.

Comment: .htacces foes for php. If you have permalinks off. WP won't conflict with it. Is it the first line of you .htaccess?

Comment: httaccess doesn't have any line, only redirect.

Comment: then my ideas have dried up sorry :( I hope my retag will attract people who do know

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a condition to the query (?Subject=Mistake-19) and escape the "." (using a slash).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Subject=Mistake-19$
RewriteRule ^index\.php?$ http://www.domain.com/?p=51? [R=301]
```